# hiding an element in javascript array

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

```
var question= dataQuestions;
```

I am loading `dataQuestions` which is an array collection.

Next, I am adding another item at position `0` as following

```
question.splice(0,0,{"Qid":0,"Answer":null,"Text":""}
```

Now, I call the following function:

```
function insertData(sQ, question) {
        sQ.kendoDropDownList({
            dataTextField : "Text",
            dataValueField : "Qid",
            dataSource : question

        });
    }
```

So now my dropdown contains few questions like "what is....?", but at position`0` there will be an empty row.
I want that empty row to hide or be non-clickable. (based on my click on any other row in the dropdown, some functionality happens).

Any help?

Comment: Sorry.. but why are you adding an element with empty text if you don't want it?

Comment: @some I need it for another functionality

Comment: Do you need it to be in the dropbox or just in `question`. If it is the later you can easily remove the first element with `question.slice(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a few options to pass an array without the first item to the dropdownlist.

The simplest if probably to use `dataQuestions` instead of `questions`:

```
var question = dataQuestions;
question.unshift({"Qid":0,"Answer":null,"Text":""});

function insertData(sQ, question) {
    sQ.kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField : "Text",
        dataValueField : "Qid",
        dataSource : dataQuestions
    });
}
```

Comment: is there any possibility of making that particular item non clickable in kendoDropDownList

Answer (score 0):

Grab the first element with javascript (or jQuery if present) and add a "disabled" attribute to it.

Something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/rU9mp/